# Why is input text cut off if it includes < sign followed by some text

Tags: html, forms, post, http-post

Why input text is cut off on form submission if input string has `<` sign followed by some text without space, e.g. `<abc`. But it works fine when there is a space after `<`, e.g. `< abc`

HTML

```
<form name="testform" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="title" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

If you provide input value as `This is a sample <string` and submit. Received value via POST is `This is a sample`. However when you submit `This is a sample < string` (notice the space after <) then it's received correctly.

Server-side (PHP)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST); // outputs "This is a sample " instead of "This is a sample <string" 
}
?>
```

What's the reason for this?

Comment: It won't be. The problem is that the server side code you haven't shared with us is outputting it as HTML and `<` has special meaning in HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php is probably a suplicate but the question fails to so much as specify the server side language involved.

Comment: Yup, duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php). `<string` is treated as an HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

The reason would be that the < symbol is a special character. Presumably in your post you'll be stripping out anything potentially harmful, possibly `htmlentities`, and your validation could be seeing it as a potential threat, so it removes the tag from the string.